# I want to use windows runtime API in the development of unity's universal windows platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi, uwp, windows-runtime

I would like to use the windows runtime API in the development of unity's universal windows platform.

I made the following script with reference to [this site](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html).

```
#define ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class test : MonoBehaviour
{

 void Start()
 {
     #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
         Debug.Log(Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager.AdvertisingId);

     #endif

 }
}
```

However, I get an error like this and it doesn't work.

“error CS0103: The name 'Windows' does not exist in      the current context”

If anyone knows the solution, please let me know.

**What I tried**

・Set the API Compatibility Level to .NET Standard 2.0 in Player Settings (Edit> Project Settings> Player)

・Change the target platform to universal windows platform

・Try the above with Unity 2021.1.15, 2020.3.14f1, 2018.4.36f1.

Referenced site
https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2021.1/Manual/IL2CPP-WindowsRuntimeSupport.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html

Comment: "an error like this", an error like what? What are the details of the error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The error looks like this.
error CS0103: The name'Windows' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you look up what that error means? Do you understand how C# resolves references?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first line.

Unity defines ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT when it's available, and it's only available when building for UWP. With it defined explicitly at the top of the file, the code within the #if/#endif block will *always* be compiled, regardless if Windows Runtime APIs are available at the point of compilation or not. And when they're not (for instance, when the Unity editor compiles code for itself rather than for UWP), you get compilation errors.